# How do you create a filter to MOVE emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I get a lot of email alerts that I need but don't want cluttering up my inbox.  If I right click on them, there is an option to move them to a folder.  I want to set up a filter to do that automatically, but when I create the filter, there is not an option to do that.  There is only an option to apply a label, which makes it show up in both the folder *and* in the inbox.  How do I create a filter to actually *move* the emails?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that Gmail is not consistent in how things are worded.  What the move command does when you right-click on an email is to add the label of the "folder" you are moving it to AND remove the "Inbox" label (aka Archive it).

So, to create a filter that does the same thing as the right-click "move" function, you need to check both the option to "Apply the label" of the folder you want it to go to *and* check the option for "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)"

Comment: worked like a charm.  thanks

Answer (score -1):

At this moment, Gmail doesn’t allow us to create new folder like before anymore. You only can create a new label. Thus, there will be no option to move email to folder, just label. The one you have seen on the left panel is label, not folder.

Comment: But if you right click on an email, you have an option to move it to that label, which removes it from the inbox and the email only shows up under that label

Comment: So you have to ask how to move emails to a label, not a folder. You have posted a wrong question at the beginning.